# can't POST binary data as a DataView in IE 11

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11, binary-data, typed-arrays

I'm trying to `POST` some binary data as a `DataView`, but IE 11 seems to be either converting it or somehow misrepresenting it as `[Object object]` instead.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8000/key', false)
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Custom-Header-1', 'header1')
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Custom-Header-2', 'header2')
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')

// keyAsUint8 is a Uint8Array holding binary data
var keyDataView = new DataView(keyAsUint8.buffer)
xhr.send(keyDataView)
```

In IE's dev tools, inspecting the request body reveals that the data is being sent as `[Object object]` (or perhaps an empty object `{}`).

[image: IE dev tools - broken data]

If I comment out the line that creates the `DataView` object, and just send the `Uint8Array` itself, `xhr.send(keyAsUint8)`, then the binary data is sent as expected.

Chrome and Firefox seem to be handling this correctly...

Chrome:
[image: Chrome dev tools]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox dev tools]

According to [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=typedarrays), IE 11 supports Typed Arrays:

[image: can i use typed arrays]

What's happening in IE 11? Why is the binary data being transformed to the `[Object object]` string? Chrome, Firefox, and Edge work as expected, so what's different about IE 11 that causes this ?

Comment: snafu? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I guess so... that's pretty terrible though.

Comment: well, ie11 is pretty old, and the binary ajax stuff is pretty new...

Comment: true, but IE claims support. so either IE's docs are straight up wrong, or they just have a bug. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536736

Comment: are you sure that doc is for ie11? it look vague to me...

Comment: not 100% sure, but I don't think there's IE 11 specific docs. I think they have general docs, with notes if there's differences in the versions. "This section contains the current and legacy APIs for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge."

Comment: Not sure why you try to send a view. A view does not hold any data of its own. It simply references the underlying ArrayBuffer. Did you try sending the ArrayBuffer itself? (ie. just `keyAsUint8.buffer`)